# How to add some metadata to Temporal table for saving in history table only

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

Is it possible to add some metadata (like username, ...) into history table of temporal table?

For example if I have below table

```sql
-- Create a Temporal Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sample
(
  SampleId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , SampleDate date NOT NULL
  -- Other fields...
  , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
 )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.SampleHistory));
```

I want to know how to insert some new record to this table with some additional metadata store in `SampleHistory` for example something like below

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sample]
           ([SampleDate]
           ,[SampleHistory].[Editor])
     VALUES
           ('13/07/1400'
            ,'soroshsabz')
```

Comment: No, but you *could* have a "lastupdateby" column in your table, which is `UPDATE`d with the details of the connected user in in your process. (This would not help with `DELETE`s` mind).

Comment: That's data, not metadata and needs to be stored in proper columns, using the correct types. Temporal tables aren't audit tables. They are used to a version of a table's data at a specific point in time, not store arbitrary data.  If you want an `Editor` or `ModifiedBy` column, you'll have to add it to the actual table, with a trigger that stores a value like `USER` or `SYSTEM_USER`

Comment: But as you can see in https://www.sqlshack.com/temporal-tables-in-sql-server/ many usage of temporal table used for auditing and showing history of important changes to customer for important table

Comment: @sorosh_sabz `used for`, not `is a`. The history table may not even be visible. Besides, what good would be a *system provided history table* if you could modify it at will?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks I correct my comment, What is meaning of not event be visible? Do you say I can not show change history of my tables to my user (client of my application) with history table?

I think it is done by something like `SELECT *, SysStartTime,SysEndTime FROM EMPLOYEE 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
order by empno, SysEndTime`

Comment: This isn't about correcting a comment, it's about understanding what temporal tables are. Your last comment isn't using the history table at all, it's using the `Employee` table and only retrieves the data stored there. You can have [anonymous history tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16#-create-a-temporal-table-with-an-anonymous-history-table) and still query historical data with `FOR SYSTEM_TIME`

Comment: A system-versioned temporal table shows you what the *system* (database) knew the data to be at a specific time. It doesn't care about the data itself, or who performed the change. If you want extra data like `Creator` or `Editor` columns, you'll have to add them to the table and fill them with whatever you consider the user to be. The SQL or Windows account you can retrieve using eg `USER` or `SYSTEM_USER`? Or some application account that has to be provided by the application itself?

Comment: Ok, if I correct understanding your comments, I have to add all of my required metadata to main table and mark as HIDDEN, then when query based on `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` I can see value of these column in specific time in past

Am I correct?

Comment: I do not this question exist solution or not, but I add request for it in https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f251229b-6b79-ee11-a81c-6045bdb7ea56