# How to exclude some column from history table in temporal table

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I have temporal table like below

```sql
-- Create a Temporal Table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sample
(
  SampleId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , SampleDate date NOT NULL
  , Data1 varchar(50)
  , Data2 varchar(50)
  -- Other fields...
  , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
 )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.SampleHistory));
```

I want to say all of changes in Data2 does not store in `HISTORY_TABLE`. In another word, in very large and big tables I just need few columns for auditing so I want to exclude other columns to reduce DB size and improve performance (in some cases most frequent changes in table occur on non-auditable column)

**How to do it?**

Comment: That isn't how a temporal tables works, As you were told by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943425/how-to-add-some-metadata-to-temporal-table-for-saving-in-history-table-only-sql#comment135640962_76943425): *"temporal tables aren't audit tables. They are used to a version of a table's data at a specific point in time."*

Comment: But as you can see in https://www.sqlshack.com/temporal-tables-in-sql-server/ many usage of temporal table used for auditing and showing history of important changes to customer for important table

Comment: And it "audits" all of the data. It's a snapshot of what the data looked like at a specific point, not what *some* of the data looked like. If you want a custom solution, you'll ned to implement a custom solution.

Comment: @ThomA Ok, custom solution is one solution ;) But I hope to exist some official solution for some of the data looked like ;)

Comment: You can use what people used since dinosaur times, a log table with a trigger that saves some data into the aforementioned log table

Comment: related to https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/332724/229432

Comment: I do not this question exist solution or not, but I add request for it in 
 https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/56566e8b-0440-ee11-a81c-000d3ae37d1e